# How Do I create a new list from distinct elements of existing list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
current_list = [#,'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
```

I want to create a new list by indexing current_list such that

```
new_list = ['1','5','9']
```

I have tried

```
new_list = current_list[1] + current_list[5] + current_list[9]
```

but I get

```
>>> 159
```

and not

```
>>> ['1','5','9']
```

How do I create new_list from current_list such that 
`new_list = ['1','5','9']` ?

New to programming and appreciate your patience.

Comment: try :  new_list = [current_list[1] , current_list[5] , current_list[9]]

Answer (score 2):

you are adding list items by using +  sign . Try:

```
new_list = [current_list[1] , current_list[5] , current_list[9]]
```

your list must contain at least 10 item otherwise you will get index out of bound error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want your result. For the new list the elements needs to be arranged as list.'+' sign is used esp. in strings (concationation) or simple addition process. So,

```
current_list = ['#','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
new_list=[current_list[1],current_list[5],current_list[9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding the indexes (e.g. `[current_list[1],current_list[5],current_list[9]]`), I would recommend programatically inserting the indexes so that it is easy to modify in the future, or you can easily generate the indexes you want from a function

```
indexes = [1, 5, 9]
current_list = ['#','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
new_list = [current_list[i] for i in indexes]
## gives ['1','5','9']
```

Now, if you need to change the indexes, you can just modify the indexes line.
Or, if down the road a user needs to specify the indexes from a file, you can read those numbers from a file. Either way, the way you generate `new_list` from `current_list` stays the same. (As a new programmer, it is important that you learn early the importance of writing code so that it is easy to modify in the future.)

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter


def make_list_from(*indices, lst):
    # Create a function that will get values from given indices
    values = itemgetter(*indices)

    # Get those values as a tuple and convert them into a list
    return list(values(lst))

current_list = ['0', '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
print(make_list_from(1, 5, 9, lst=current_list))
# ['1', '5', '9']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html):

```
from operator import itemgetter
my_indices = [1, 5, 9]

new_list = list(itemgetter(*my_indices)(current_list))
```

or you can pick the elements by your indeces using list comprehension:

```
new_list = [current_list[i] for i in my_indices]
```

similar with:

```
new_list = []

for index in my_indices:
    new_list.append(current_list[index])

print(new_list)
```

output:

```
['1', '5', '9']
```